# Related to speeding up Selenium JUnit tests

Tags: selenium, junit

I have written junit test cases using web driver backed selenium. 
I had come across a situation wherein sometimes `selenium.isElementPresent()` or `selenium.isTextPresent()` would throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

To get rid of this issue I have been using Thread.sleep() method before finding any element on the web page and it used to work fine but, in cases where the page would have already finished loading, Thread.sleep() slows down the execution of my test case.

So I would like to know is there any way that i could determine whether all the elements in a web page have finished loading, so that I won't have to arbitrarily make use of `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`waitFor`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html) instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

> "waitFor" commands wait for some condition to become true (which can be useful for testing Ajax applications). They will succeed immediately if the condition is already true. However, they will fail and halt the test if the condition does not become true within the current timeout setting (see the setTimeout action below).

[Here's an article that goes in depth about this topic](http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/selenium-wait-for-ajax-the-right-way/)

Comment: Well I think that's because you want to use the `waitFor` method that applies to finding an element, not waiting for the page to load.  Have you tried using that?

Comment: Thanks Daniel.But is there any way to determine whether a page has finished loading using selenium so that i could avoid using Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Since you are using Selenium 1, there should be a method called `waitForPageToLoad` on the `selenium` object.